# HTML parsing error for login in Vista IE8 configuration

Tags: login-errors, ie8

My users are getting "HTML Parsing error"error when they are trying to login. User is entering credentials and then clicking login making page refresh and getting this error. If any faced this similar issue.

Below is the screenshot[image]

Comment: Forget about IE8, it will not supported in couple of months anymore...

Comment: Does that mean that using IE8 users cannot login after few months.

Comment: This means "only" the end of support ([read more](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187123&language=en_US))

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a commonly known issue and the workarounds are listed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T58oAAC).

1. Install security update patch for IE 8 for Windows XP will solve the problem. 
   The patch was released back in 2011 and it is a security patch. OR
2. Set browser to use Compatibility mode.  OR
3. Disable TLS1.1, 1.2 in browser